# How does Moves app work on iOS

Tags: ios

Moves app on iOS geolocates your movements throughout the day even when the app is inactive. In addition to this it also appears to analyse core motion data to identify if you have walked, cycled or taken another form of transport (walking with your phone in a suitcase on wheels reports as a cycle).

What iOS methods and techniques can the Moves app use to continuously capture this data without the application having been open? Geofencing? Background processes?

Comment: Hi Ross did you get how they identify walked,cycled or other transport used?

Comment: @ajay no I didn't. Presume core motion sampling.

Comment: I think that, besides core motion, they also would need to do some kind of analysis between consecutive CLLocations, determining the speed between each one. Combined with CoreMotion that should do the trick. I honestly can't understand how their "map tracking" can be so accurate even in Low Energy mode. Background location updates are really hard on battery power, and significant location updates are simply not accurate enough.

Comment: Hi @Ross , Did you alreadly known how the app works?

Answer (score 0):

You can register an app to continue operating in the background. Have a look here at the Background Execution and Multitasking section. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html